# How To Work with Flutter Data Model and Future Builder

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

i have working with test app, its just display list of employees from api call, for that i have created data model for employee and calling it. but i get nothing i know somewhere it goes wrong help me to find out the problem(actually no errors but, its does not load the data).

here is the snippets

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/employee.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class EmployeeListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  EmployeeListScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _EmployeeListScreenState createState() => _EmployeeListScreenState();
}

class _EmployeeListScreenState extends State<EmployeeListScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Employee List"),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
          future: fetchEmployees(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
              return Center(
                child: Text("None"),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Center(child: Text("No Employees"));
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length[![enter image description here][1]][1],
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Text(snapshot.data[index]["name"]);
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            return Container();
          },
        ));
  }

  Future<List<Employee>> fetchEmployees() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        "http://192.168.1.199/projects/ci/employee/api/getEmployees",
        headers: {"accept": "application/json"});
    debugPrint("Api Finished...");

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final result = jsonDecode(response.body);
      Iterable list = result['employees'];
      print(list);
      return list.map((employee) => Employee.fromJson(employee)).toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to Load Employees");
    }
  }
}
```

see the screen shots.

[image]

i have the result while am using traditional api call without using model and factory methods, its very confusing to me also suggest me for best sites to learn these things, even i saw the official document it not clear at all.

Comment: If it is working fine when you don't map it to model, it means the problem is with the mapping of result to the model. Please verify if the mapping is done correctly or not. Also, try following the steps in the doc and see if that helps. https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Answer (score 0):

To help debug the issue, how about trying this simplified code below.  Call your `fetchEmployees()` from inside `loadSlowData()` method.

(It's not good practice to make an async call directly in `FutureBuilder future:`.  Instead, make the async call in `initState` of the `StatefulWidget`.  Since `FutureBuilder` is inside the `build()` method, and `build` could be called up to 60 times a second, you can obviously see the problem.  If you happen to use an animation on that part of the widget tree, which refresh at 60fps, you'll get that situation.)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FutureBuilderStatefulPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FutureBuilderStatefulPageState createState() => _FutureBuilderStatefulPageState();
}

class _FutureBuilderStatefulPageState extends State<FutureBuilderStatefulPage> {
  Future<String> _slowData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _slowData = loadSlowData();
  }

  Future<String> loadSlowData() async {
    // replace with your async call ↓ ↓
    return await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 'The Future has arrived');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FutureBldr Stateful'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
        future: _slowData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data));
          }
          return Center(child: Text('Loading...'));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have tried kind of your advice but nothing happen in screen, take a look at my future call, Future<List<Employee>> _fetchAllEmployees() async {
    http.Response response = await http
        .get("http://192.168.1.199/projects/ci/employee/api/getEmployees");
    var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
    var employees = responseBody['employees'];
    List allEmployees = new List();
    for (var employee in employees) {
      allEmployees.add(new Employee.fromJson(employee));//could not add this to the list, so null occured
    }
    
    return allEmployees;
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly Try snapShot.hasData instead of snapshot.data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).